# Koin injecting into WorkManager

Tags: kotlin, androidx, koin

I have a basic work manager

```
class BackgroundSyncWorker (
    appContext: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
): Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

And I want to inject my repository into this to do some work in my database. I've set Koin up correctly but can't seem to find a way of how to inject my dependency into the Worker. I've tried inheriting the KoinComponent and trying to do it using that, but `by inject()` doesn't exist, but there's two `by inject` methods that I can't find how to use. There doesn't seem to be any information on how to inject into managers, although there's a few for using dagger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This does actually work, I was just using `var` instead of val.

```
class BackgroundSyncWorker (
    appContext: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
): Worker(appContext, workerParams), KoinComponent {

    val dataSyncRepository : DataSyncRepositoryImpl by inject()

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Comment: can y post main Module config

Comment: The module is the same as a normal module for Koin

Answer (score 9):

I have noticed a couple of things from your code:

The first reason for why this does not work because you need to extend/inherit the BackgroundSyncWork from KoinComponent, so making this BackgroundSyncWork koin-aware.

```
class BackgroundSyncWorker (
    appContext: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
): Worker(appContext, workerParams), KoinComponent {

val database: Database by inject()

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Second: Also, please make sure that database object creation is properly configured in koin module. It should work with no problem.

Comment: Yeah, I got it below :), was a stupid mistake. Thanks though!

Comment: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: