# No bean found when using koin in non-activity class

Tags: android, koin

I am trying to use work manager and use Koin to get some dependencies I have setup. My work manager extends `KoinComponent` which then allows me to use `by inject` but every time I try to use a component I am trying to get I get the error

> NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class AuthenticationService. Check your definitions!

Bear in mind that I use these dependencies just fine in activities and view models

My work manager

```
class BackgroundSync(private val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams),
    KoinComponent{

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val authService:AuthenticationService by inject()
        val token = authService.getAuthToken() // Error here when trying to use it
    }
}
```

Then in my Koin module setup I have this

```
private val myModule = module {
    single<IAuthenticationService> { AuthenticationService() }
}
```

I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349196/koin-injecting-into-workmanager) as reference but I cant get it to work properly, any idea's in what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Koin you should inject exactly what you provide. In your case, in the koin module, you provide an *interface* but in `BackgroundSync` you inject the *concrete class*.

I believe you need to inject the interface:

```
class BackgroundSync(private val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams),
    KoinComponent{

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val authService:IAuthenticationService by inject()
        val token = authService.getAuthToken() // Error here when trying to use it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> NoBeanDefFoundException, means without providing the dependency to koin component you are trying to access the object.
>
> Try providing the instance to the koin component like below

```
private val myModule = module {
    single { AuthenticationService() }
}
```